# Find and Replace first line with sed expression

Tags: php, regex, sed

A php injection attack on our shared hosted web server has injected malicious code in the first line of many php files. Like as below :

```
<?php $uifbpsmx = '8R#>q%V<*#fopoV (large number of such characters followed by); ?><?php
```

Can you suggest a sed expression to find and replace (if found) this first line in php files with normal php opening tag : `<?php`

Comment: Maybe `sed i.bak 's/^<?php .*<?php$/<?php/' file`? If a line starts with `<?php` + space and ends with `<?php`, replace the line with `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

To just keep last occurrence of `<?php` in first line:

```
sed i.bak '1{s/^<?php \$uifbpsmx.*>\(<?php\)/\1/;}' file
```

`-i` is for editing the file in place. Edited files are backed up with `.bak` extension.